# Initialization of structure with ternary operator

Tags: c, struct, initialization, ternary-operator

Why the ternary operator cannot be used to initialize a structure type, while it can be used to initialize a base type like *int*?

Example code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ODD 1

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  static struct pair_str {
    int first; 
    int second; 
  } pair = ( ODD ) ?  {1,3} : {2,4}; // ERROR

  printf("pair %d %d\n", pair.first, pair.second); 

  int number = (ODD) ? 1 :2;  // FINE

  return 0;
```

}

Compiler errors :

```
/home/giuseppe/struct.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/giuseppe/struct.c:12:23: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
/home/giuseppe/struct.c:12:29: error: expected expression before ‘:’ token
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, use C99 compound literals:

```
pair = odd ? (struct pair_str){ 1, 3 } : (struct pair_str){ 2, 4 };
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine if the structure is not static. Why can 't I use with static structure?

Comment: Another use of CL. +1.

Comment: @haccks You mean "common logic"? :) (Thanks!)

Comment: @H2CO3; I mean to say *compound literal* but from now CL will stand for *common logic* :D

Comment: @PHIfounder We all need a shot of CL, there are so much posts missing it! :D

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes we do , in fact I need a lot :P :P