# Am I correctly creating and passing this C array to Objective-C method and referencing it with a property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I created a C array like this:

```
unsigned char colorComps[] = {2, 3, 22,   55, 9, 1};
```

which I want to pass to an initializer of an Objective-C object.

So I think I have to put the array on the heap:

```
size_t arrayByteSize = numColorCompVals * sizeof(unsigned char);
unsigned char *colorCompsHeap = (unsigned char*)malloc(arrayByteSize);
```

Then I have to write my first "stack memory array" to the heap array in for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numColorCompVals; i++) {
   colorCompsHeap[i] = colorComps[i];
}
```

**Side question: Is there a more elegant solution to avoid the for-loop step?**

And then I pass it to the method:

defined as

```
- (id)initWithColorCompsC:(unsigned char *)colorCompsHeap;

TheObject *obj = [[TheObject alloc] initWithColorCompsC:colorCompsHeap];
```

`TheObject` has a property to hold the C-array:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned char *colorComps;
```

And in -dealloc I free it:

```
free(_colorComps);
```

This is in theory. I use ARC for Objective-C. **Am I doing this correct or is there a better way?**

Comment: You'd probably be better off allocating and copying the array in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TheObject` is going to free the array, then its `init` method should be the one to make the copy, NOT the caller.  That way each instance of `TheObject` make its own copy and frees its own copy, it *owns* that copy.

Also, then it doesn't matter where the parameter to the init comes from, stack or heap.  It won't matter if the `init` method makes a copy of it.

Use memcpy to make the copy, with `sizeof` the destination array, like this for the .m file:

```
@interface PTTEST ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned char *colorComps;
@end

@implementation PTTEST

- (void)dealloc
{
    free(_colorComps);
}

- (id)initWithColorCompsC:(unsigned char *)colorComps
       numberOfColorComps:(unsigned)numberOfColorComps
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // compute size based on sizeof the first element (in case
        // the element type get changed later, this still works right)
        size_t arraySize = sizeof(colorComps[0]) * numberOfColorComps;

        _colorComps = malloc(arraySize);

        memcpy(_colorComps, colorComps, arraySize);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: One more question: Why wouldn't size_t arraySize = sizeof(colorComps) work?

Comment: @ProudMember because that returns the size of the pointer, not the array itself.

Comment: And how about sizeof(&colorComps)?

Comment: @H2CO3 Care to explain?

Comment: @ProudMember Explain what?

Comment: `colorComps` is *pointer* to an array, `sizeof(colorComps)` gives the size of the pointer.  `&colorComps` is a pointer to the pointer, still won't work.

Answer (score 2):

This seems fine, however...

1. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858);
2. and don't reinvent `memcpy()`. Instead of your for loop, write `memcpy(dest, src, size)`.

Comment: Even better - use `memcpy` with a C99 compound literal array. Much more consise.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yeah, [I am aware of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896743/initialization-of-structure-with-ternary-operator/17896781#17896781) (I just didn't think this was the question here.)

Comment: Richard can you explain what you mean with a C99 compound literal array?

Comment: According to the documentation memcpy is for chars. What about other data types? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm

Comment: @ProudMember: `memcpy` copies data.  It is not picky about data type.  The documentation you link to clearly specifies that it takes `void *` arguments, not `char` or `char *`.

Comment: @ProudMember It's not for `char`s. It's for anything. (That's why it accepts `void *` and `const void *`.)

Comment: In the linked example: memcpy(dest, src, strlen(src)+1); - why add one byte?

Comment: @ProudMember For the 0-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems correct to me, you are filling `colorCompsHeap`(an array of unsigned chars) with the values of `colorComps[]` (an array of doubles)

```
unsigned char u = 0.2;

printf("%f\n", (double)u);
```

Outputs `0.000000`

Comment: @DavidRF Then it was someone else, and he **still** didn't leave any explanation.